# How do I get a bash script working on FreeBSD, OpenBSD and Linux without modifying it?

Tags: linux, bash, freebsd, openbsd

Sorry, the headline might be a bit irritating, but I didn't know anything better. Anyway, I want a bash script to work on FreeBSD, OpenBSD and Linux without modifying it, but bash isn't located at the same place in Linux and BSD.

So, if I write `#!/bin/bash` then it won't work on BSD, because the bash shell is located in `/usr/local/bin/bash` there. Is there any solution to get this script working on both?

Or do I really need to ship two scripts with different paths...?

Comment: Also note that on a FreeBSD system there's *no guarantee whatsoever* that bash will be available at all, it's an optional install...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Using `env` in the shebang (`#!/usr/bin/env bash`) should make the script OS agnostic.

Answer (score 4):

I like the answer about using `#!/usr/bin/env bash`
It is an interesting and excellent answer, but that would only work if bash is in the path.

Another option might be to use `#!/bin/sh` which is the most universally compatible shell location.
Then, have the script do something in `sh`, such as check where `bash` is installed (if `bash` is even installed).  Another option might be to have `bash` exist to both locations.  Making another installation may sound like overkill, but this goal could be accomplished as simply as creating a hard link so that bash actually exists in both locations.